# Javascript Filter array list by id field into a new variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a data list which looks like this:

```
{"people":[
    {
    "id":"100",
    "name":"name 1",
    "desc":"desc 1" 
    },
    {
    "id":"192",
    "name":"name 2",
    "desc":"desc 2" 
    },
    {
    "id":"324",
    "name":"name 3",
    "desc":"desc 3" 
    }
]}
```

I have it stored in a variable:

myVar

What I need to do is to cut the list down to only the data from id - 192 (for example).

So that in the end I'm left with:

```
{"people":[
    {
    "id":"192",
    "name":"name 2",
    "desc":"desc 2" 
    }
]}
```

So myNewVar =

```
{"people":[
    {
    "id":"192",
    "name":"name 2",
    "desc":"desc 2" 
    }
]}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Should be as straight forward as just filtering it

```
myVar.people = myVar.people.filter( x => x.id === "192");
```